# How do I redirect IE11 to Edge like Stack Overflow

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, browser

When you navigate to https://stackoverflow.com in IE11, it redirects the user to Edge with the following tab open: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-website-you-were-trying-to-reach-doesn-t-work-with-internet-explorer-8f5fc675-cd47-414c-9535-12821ddfc554?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

How do I implement this in my own site? Is there a meta tag that can enable this?

EDIT: Here's a clip of what it looks like. Tried on Windows 10. https://streamable.com/nwtt22

Comment: What you're describing doesn't happen for me. I don't think it's something that can be coded. You can't control the user's browser.

Comment: https://streamable.com/nwtt22 Here's a video to show what's going on

Comment: That is to to with the browser's policy, it is not code on the website. [Microsoft.com: Configure IE mode policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#redirect-sites-from-ie-to-microsoft-edge)

Answer (score 10):

Ah yes, I wondered this too, and also assumed to be a browser only thing.

Sure enough!
It's the ie_to_edge_bho (Browser Helper Object) DLL file found in the Edge Program files.

I was curious enough to Hex edit the DLL file and found the URL in which it pulls these approved sites from... almost like a master/default list.

Yes, it's built into the BHO, no it's not stored locally from what I can tell.
[(Screenshot of Hex editor)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abi5i.png)

Here is the link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2133855

Which forwards to https://edge.microsoft.com/neededge/v1

I have no idea how you get your own site on this list, but I figured I would add this information. :)

Comment: If anybody knows how to get on this list, please comment!

Comment: Here's the list: https://edge.microsoft.com/neededge/v1

Comment: @jxn You need to e-mail Microsoft. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 7):

I was wondering this too. After reading Joshua Joppie's answer, I did some Googling and found [this webpage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/ie-to-microsoft-edge-redirection#request-an-update-to-the-ie-compatibility-list).

Turns out, you need to e-mail Microsoft to get your site added to the Edge-only list (how to do so is explained on [that page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/ie-to-microsoft-edge-redirection#request-an-update-to-the-ie-compatibility-list)). I'm not sure if they'll take a request from anyone, or whether you need to be a big website, like Stack Overflow. It's worth trying anyway, as the only requirement they give is this:

> The IE compatibility list is designed to work with public sites only.

To be honest, I've no idea why they didn't just make a `<meta>` tag for it. It would be much easier.

If I have time (which I doubt), I plan to make a JS programme that mimics the functionality of a website's presence on this list and I will link to it here. You could always do a user agent check that redirects the user to `microsoft-edge:https://example.com` (where example.com is your website) if it detects them using Internet Explorer.

Comment: With the microsoft-edge prefix, it opens a new tab is there a way to have that redirect use the current tab?

Answer (score 6):

Need to add the below script in the head tag to redirect your website in Edge browser

```
<script>
   if(/MSIE \d|Trident.*rv:/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      window.location = 'microsoft-edge:' + window.location;
      setTimeout(function() {
         window.open('', '_self', '').close();
         // window.location = 'https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/we-recommend-viewing-this-website-in-microsoft-edge-160fa918-d581-4932-9e4e-1075c4713595?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us';            
      }, 0);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is controlled by Edge Chromium group policy not code. You can refer to the steps below to set the group policy to achieve the goal:

**1. Send all sites not included in the Enterprise Mode Site List to Microsoft Edge**

This setting lets you decide whether to open all sites not included in the Enterprise Mode Site List in Microsoft Edge. If you use this setting, you **must** also turn on the Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Use the Enterprise Mode IE website list policy setting and you **must** include at least one site in the Enterprise Mode Site List.

- Open Group Policy Editor.
- Click **Computer Configuration > Administrative Tools > Windows Components > Internet Explorer**.
- Double-click **Send all sites not included in the Enterprise Mode Site List to Microsoft Edge**.
- Select **Enabled**.
- Click **OK** or **Apply** to save these settings.

**2. Configure which channel of Microsoft Edge to use for opening redirected sites**

This policy enables you to configure up to three versions of Microsoft Edge to open a redirected site (in order of preference).

- In the same path of Group Policy Editor, double-click **Configure which channel of Microsoft Edge to use for opening redirected sites**.
- Select **Enabled**.
- Under **Options**, select your top three choices for the channel to use - Internet Explorer will redirect to the highest ranked choice that the user has installed on that device:

  - Microsoft Edge Stable
  - Microsoft Edge Beta version 77 or later
  - Microsoft Edge Dev version 77 or later
  - Microsoft Edge Canary version 77 or later
  - Microsoft Edge version 45 or earlier
- Click **OK** or **Apply** to save these settings.

**3. Use the Enterprise Mode IE website list**

This policy setting lets you specify where to find the list of websites you want opened using Enterprise Mode IE.

- Create or reuse a Site List XML. Sample file is like below:

site.xml:

```
<site-list version="8">
  <created-by>
    <tool>EMIESiteListManager</tool>
    <version>10.0.14357.1004</version>
    <date-created>08/20/2020 07:45:39</date-created>
  </created-by>
  <site url="www.example.com">
    <compat-mode>IE7</compat-mode>
    <open-in>IE11</open-in>
  </site>
</site-list>
```

- In the same path of Group Policy Editor, double-click **Use the Enterprise Mode IE website list**.
- Select **Enabled**.
- Under **Options**, type the location of website list. If it's in local, you can set it like this: **file://D:/site.xml**.
- Click **OK** or **Apply** to save these settings.

Comment: These solutions would be for one's own machine, right? I get the impression that he wants to redirect visitors to a website.

Comment: What he want is impossible. My solution explains how to achieve what he describing in the thread.

Comment: But I can confirm that these settings are NOT applied to my machine, and yet my machine redirects StackOverflow (and Youtube) from IE to Edge every time. Surely there must be something else going on, if only a global Microsoft-maintained list.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple to add your domain to the redirection list.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/ie-to-microsoft-edge-redirection#request-an-update-to-the-ie-compatibility-list

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-neededge

> Request an update to the IE compatibility list The IE compatibility
> list is an XML file on microsoft.com. The list is regularly updated in
> response to user and website developer requests to have websites added
> or removed. Updates to the list are automatically downloaded to user
> machines.
>
> Email the following information to ietoedge@microsoft.com for your
> website to be added or removed from the IE compatibility list.
>
> Owner name Corporate title Email address Company name Street address
> Website address

Comment: Unfortunately, it only allows public websites to be submitted. It seems the way to do this for intranet sites is #3 listed in the answer beginning with "This is controlled by Edge Chromium group policy not code..."

Comment: Yea, check for the user agent and use microsoft-edge:xy to redirect IE to edge :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain that Microsoft checks its "Enterprise Mode Site List" in order to decide whether to open the webpage or direct users to Edge. You can find more information about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/what-is-enterprise-mode