# how to redirect IE to Edge like youtube, twitter, stackoverflow without permission

Tags: redirect, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

When you navigate to youtube, twitter, StackOverflow in IE11. you can find your browser opened Microsoft Edge without permission.

I wanna know how to do that, and apply my own web site.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSA92.png)

that is the permission that I said.

Comment: The behavior you describing in the thread is due to applying this policy: [Redirect sites from IE to Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#redirect-sites-from-ie-to-microsoft-edge). It's controlled by group policy not code. So you can't add some code in your website to achieve this. Besides, stackoverflow is an English forum but the image you put is of Korean. I suggest you to put English information for better understanding.

Comment: You can also refer to this similar thread: [How do I redirect IE11 to Edge like Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731061/how-do-i-redirect-ie11-to-edge-like-stack-overflow)