# Force Internet Explorer to open a website in Edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, meta

I just visited the apple.com website in the Internet Explorer and noticed, Internet Explorer opens the website directly in Edge and [shows this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-website-you-were-trying-to-reach-doesn-t-work-with-internet-explorer-8f5fc675-cd47-414c-9535-12821ddfc554?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) in the IE-window.

I'd like to implement this to my websites too, so i dont have to opimize all features for the IE. Do you have an idea, how this is possible?

I found this snippet, but it doesnt work: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

**The answer is very simple can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/ie-to-microsoft-edge-redirection#request-an-update-to-the-ie-compatibility-list**

Comment: I think it's controlled by Edge Chromium group policy not code. You can refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731061/how-do-i-redirect-ie11-to-edge-like-stack-overflow/63736842#63736842) before about how does the GPO work. You can check the GPO setting in your machine and refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#redirect-sites-from-ie-to-microsoft-edge).

Comment: Besides, Islam's solution can also be a workaround, to use Edge Chromium you can use `shell.run("microsoft-edge:http://yoursite");`. But it won't show the page you provide in the question so I think the result you see is still controlled by GPO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect IE11 to Edge like Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731061/how-do-i-redirect-ie11-to-edge-like-stack-overflow)

Comment: @Llamax Yess, thats what i was looking for. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Run this code at the very start of your website :

```js
if (isIE()) {
  // We open the website in Chrome if it's IE, note that ActiveXObject only works on IE
  var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  shell.run("Chrome https://google.com");
}

function isIE() {
  ua = navigator.userAgent;
  // MSIE used to detect old browsers and Trident used to newer ones
  var is_ie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || ua.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;
  return is_ie;
}
```

It's a hack, but it should work if the user has active X enabled on his browser. If not, he'll get a prompt to enable it.